# Changing purpose of stay from travel to work in Schengen

Tags: schengen-visas, visa-free-entry, work, turkish-citizens, change-purpose-of-travel

I am in a peculiar situation that German embassy in my country (Turkey) is also rather unclear about: I have two valid passports, one Green (i.e. allows free travel in Schengen area as a tourist) and one Red (does not allow any visa-free entrance to Schengen area). Green one is gonna expire in a year or so, hence the need for the Red.

So I will be working in Germany starting from September 1, and got my visa for that purpose on the Red passport. While applying for the visa, I asked the officer there if I can get into Germany with my Green and work with Red, she said yes as long as I did all work-related procedures with the Red one. Accordingly, I got my plane tickets on a cheaper and more appropriate time, knowing that the visa may have a later date of entry.

Then, I started doubting the validity of officer's statement and sent a mail to the same embassy, asking for clarification. Their response was the opposite, saying that I can't get in Germany with Green and work with Red, as I would be registered as a tourist. Their response was rather unprofessional, I must say, and rudely dismissed my follow-up question.

So here's my question for friends here: Is it possible to change my purpose of visit within Germany, as I already have the necessary permits? If not possible (or would take too much time), can I just have a two-day vacation in Croatia with my Green passport, and then come back to Germany when my visa starts with the Red passport? Would it solve my issues?

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Why not simply renew the "green" passport? Anyway, questions about long-term travel for work do not belong here but at [expats.se].

Comment: Thanks, also asking it in Expatriates. But change-purpose-of-travel is a valid tag here and not there, so I will also keep the question here I guess. I can't renew the Green passport unfortunately.

Comment: Why can't you renew the "green" passport? If you mean you're no longer a citizen of the country that issued it, then you cannot legally use it *now*; doing so would be fraud.

Comment: No, it is related to my status in the country. Green passport, or Special (Hususi) Passport as known in Turkey, is given to me because of my mother who is an officer there, and I will not be able to renew it since I won't be a student living with her anymore. How can I have the passport of that country while not being a citizen?

Comment: Just for clarity, "Green" and "Red" are passports from two different countries, right? Work would not be allowed with "Green" passport without a visa anyway, right? And you want to use "Green" just because you want to fly to Germany before the visa in "Red" starts, correct?

Comment: @HenningMakholm I believe both passports are issued by Turkey.  Its official passports are green; normal passports are red.

Comment: @jcaron they're both Turkish passports; one is an official passport.

Comment: Ahah well the system is rather complicated in our country. Both "green" and "red" passports are issued by Turkey, and valid. But the rest is correct.

Comment: OK, so the remaining question is "you want to use "Green" just because you want to fly to Germany before the visa in "Red" starts, correct?"

Comment: @jcaron yup, exactly.

Comment: At the very least the workaround at the end of your question (exiting the Schengen Area with the Green passport and then re-entering with the Red one with the visa) would work. Not sure however if it would actually be an issue if you initially entered with the Green one, especially as you could enter the Schengen Area somewhere else but Germany. The only issue would be if they ever check the entry stamp date while doing any administrative processes in Germany, which I don't know.

Comment: It seems like the two passports allow you to do two distinct things. Entering with your green passport, you’re a tourist. With your red passport, you’re allowed to work. This question discusses transitioning from a C to D visa but might be relevant to your situation https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/87436/do-i-have-to-leave-the-schengen-area-if-i-have-a-short-term-c-visa-that-will-e

Comment: @jcaron exactly what I was thinking. Nobody appears to have any idea regarding to the last part.

Comment: @Traveler I think the situation is very similar. Only, the two-passport thingy complicates things a little, so a visa-run still might be the necessary step here. Thank you!