# Can I apply for a student Schengen visa while holding a tourist visa?

Tags: germany, student-visas

In order to continue my studies in Germany, it is necessary that I take an exam called the Aufnahmeprüfung. Normally, when one receives an invitation to this exam, they apply for a student visa. However, this visa can take quite a long time, so I am considering taking a tourist visa for the time period of the exam and simultaneously using the invitation I have to apply for a student visa in order to proceed normally afterwards.

Is this allowed? Would there be any repercussions of this?

One complication I think is that the date of the student visa and the tourist visa may be the same. I heard that one cannot have more than one Schengen visa at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I heard one can't have more than one schengen visa at a time.

That is correct, you cannot get 2 **Schengen Visa**s (Type C) for an overlaping period.

If the Student Visa is based on [§16b - Further education [full-time studies] - Residence Act](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_aufenthg/englisch_aufenthg.html#p0275), then it is a **National Visa** (Type D, longer than 90 days), to cover the period for your studies.

If you apply for a **Schengen Visa** (Type C, up to 90 days), giving studies (to take the entry exam) as the reason, it it will not be in conflict with the national visa.

Comment: My problem is, can I apply for type C, then simultaneously for type D before type C expires? @Mark Johnson

Comment: @TrystwithFreedom Yes, because they are 2 different types of visas that serve 2 different purposes (first, short-term to take the test. second, to stay long-term after you have been accepted)

Comment: @TrystwithFreedom Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/87436/do-i-have-to-leave-the-schengen-area-if-i-have-a-short-term-c-visa-that-will-e