# Is writing exams valid reason to apply for tourist schengen visas?

Tags: germany, tourist-visas, study, student-visas

To continue my studies in Germany, it is necessary that I write an exam called the *Aufnahmepruefung*. Normally, when one gets the invitation to this exam, they apply for a student visa. However, this visa takes quite long, so I am considering taking a tourist visa for the time period of the exam, and simultaneously using the invitation I have to apply for a student visa, to proceed normally afterwards.

Is this allowed? Would there be any repercussions of this?

Comment: Have you asked the school/university/institute that you are in contact with?

Comment: I had sent an email to my embassy but I'll check again @NicolasFormichella

Comment: The link was very confusing, did you mean to link to https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/179199/can-an-indian-file-for-a-national-and-a-schengen-visa-applications-at-once? How is this question different?

Comment: And also answered here: [germany - Can I apply for a student Schengen visa while holding a tourist visa? - Travel Stack Exchange](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/179184/95267): If you apply for a **Schengen Visa** (Type C, up to 90 days), giving studies (to take the entry exam) as the reason, it it will not be in conflict with the national visa.