# Can an Indian file for a national and a schengen visa applications at once?

Tags: visas, schengen, germany

Would it be possible for an Indian to file for both national student visa and Schengen visa at the same time?

[This previous question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/179180/can-i-apply-for-a-student-schengen-visa-while-holding-a-tourist-visa) is not the same as this one. The previous one's accepted answer revolves around applying for a national student visa after in possesion of a schengen visa. My question is rather differnet, I am asking if I can open multiple visa applications at once.

By student visa I mean the long stay visa (more than year or so)

[Crosspost](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/24997/can-an-indian-file-for-multipile-schengen-visa-application-at-once)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I apply for a student Schengen visa while holding a tourist visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/179180/can-i-apply-for-a-student-schengen-visa-while-holding-a-tourist-visa)

Comment: Then make it clear in your question whether the 'student' visa you mean a **National Visa** (Type D) or a Schengen Visa (Type C) where the given purpose is **Study**.

Comment: Student Visa for a course extending more than a year @MarkJohnson

Comment: A national Type D visa allows you 90/180 days entry to other Schengen countries as a tourist anyway. What is your objective in considering applying for C and D visas at the same time? Would you be applying to the same country for both?

Comment: @Traveller He needs to attend an entry exam at a specific date before the national visa has been issued.

Comment: @MarkJohnson What proof of having *passed* the entry exam is required in order to apply for a national visa based on confirmed entry to the study programme? Are national visas granted solely on a plan to sit / having sat the entry exam but without knowing the outcome?

Comment: @Traveller Based on [§16b - Further education - Residence Act](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_aufenthg/englisch_aufenthg.html#p0275): *if he or she has been accepted by the educational institution.* is what is required. For the exam itsself only a Schengen visa, giving studies (to take the entry exam) as the reason, is required.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Ok, so applying simultaneously for a tourist C type visa (to sit the entrance exam) and a long stay D visa (to complete the study course) is *not* possible, because for the D visa application the OP would have had to pass the entrance exam in order to get accepted by the educational institution for the subsequent study course?

Comment: The thing is, many students have told me they applied for the student visa based on the invitation to the exam. Or so I understand @Traveller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as the visa rules are concerned, there is no reason not to grant a Schengen Visa while the National visa is pending to attend the entry exam (which sound more like a qualification test (Aufnahmeprüfung) than a language test).

> The thing is, many students have told me they applied for the student visa based on the invitation to the exam.

[§16b (5)(1)(a)](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_aufenthg/englisch_aufenthg.html#p0285) could be understood to fit the condition for an entry exam.

> (5) A foreigner may be granted a temporary residence permit, if
>
> 1. the foreigner has been accepted by a state or state-recognised or comparable educational institution
>    a) for full-time studies, **with acceptance dependent on a condition** which does not aim at attending measures to prepare for studies,
>    ...
>
> ...

Comment: The visa category is often called Studienbewerbervisum, e.g. https://taipei.diplo.de/tw-de/-/2451606. It can be a bit peculiar to obtain one, as the real purpose of stay is harder to justify than normal student visa with guaranteed place.

Comment: Isn't there on the Indian diplo @xngtng

Comment: @xngtng *Aufenthaltserlaubnis zum Zweck der Studienbewerbung* is based on §17(2): [§17 - Seeking a vocational training place or a place in higher education](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_aufenthg/englisch_aufenthg.html#p0350). This is different since the OP has found a place and wishes to attend the entry exam of the found Institution.